# Installing plugin the Capacitor way still requires the Cordova plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

When I install for example the Insomnia plugin the Capacitor way like so:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-insomnia
npm install @ionic-native/insomnia
ionic cap sync
```

It still requires me to install the cordova plugin like this:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-insomnia
```

In order to work. Otherwise it says: `plugin_not_installed`

My steps to make it work are:

> Step 1: Add Insomnia to providers (@ionic-native/insomnia/ngx)
>
> Step 2: Inject Insomnia within the constructor `private insomnia: Insomnia`

Am I forgetting something or do I just really need to `ionic cordova plugin add` for plugins that are not fully supported yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably obvious for most but just in case someone else might face this problem..

When you use capacitor you shouldn't start your server with `ionic cordova run` or `ionic cordova build` anymore.

Obviously you need to start it [this way for livereload](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/live-reload#using-with-ionic-cli):

```
ionic cap run android -l --external
ionic cap run ios -l --external
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your application is using cordova and not capacitor..
Remove your platforms folder, and just to make sure and remove unnecessary cordova files which will increase your app size, remove `cordova-android` and `cordova-ios` from your `package.json`.. You do not need that for running your app based on capacitor.

Then, run this command.

```
ionic build
npx cap add android
npx cap add ios
```

For each successive build, in case you add or remove a plugin, use `npx cap sync`

Otherwise use `npx cap copy`

[Reference Docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started/with-ionic)